# Microchip Registry questions

Tags: dogs

My dog got her microchip implanted in Korea.

When we moved back to the US, I was told by a vet that I have to do the registering myself online. So I did. I used petlink.net, but it seems like they require payment to complete it. So the first question is: do I need to make payment to complete it?

I also found a different free registry site: https://www.freepetchipregistry.com/

As the name of the service suggests, I registered for free, however, because I'm using a free service, I'm afraid it might somehow be lacking in one way or another compared to premium services. Would that be the case?

Do I need to register the chip in multiple services to improve my chance of finding her when lost? What's the process like?

All in all, my question revolves around what the process is like when my dog is found, and what I can do to improve my chance of recovering her.

Thank you so much all you wonderful souls for answering my questions!

Answer (score 0):

Register your pets microchip number with your local Animal Control office. Police, Sheriff, and Animal Control vehicles are routinely supplied with chip scanners. In the event that your dog gets out and they find them, they will be able to scan your dogs chip and return him/her to you.

In the U.S., you need to provide a record of your dog's Rabies vacination and pay for the County tags (anyway). It won't cost anything extra to give them the microchip data. After all, they are the one's most likely to come across your dog if it should get out.